# open files limit

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I am getting "too many open files" error when I try to insert records in a partitioned table.

mysql> insert into test.ox_data_geo_span select * from vserv.ox_data_geo_span limit 100;

ERROR 1016 (HY000): Can't open file: './test/ox_data_geo_span.frm' (errno: 24)

perror 24

OS error code  24:  Too many open files

If I execute "flush tables" then I am able to insert data into some other table. But I need a way to insert into many tables at a time.

Comment: which engine you are using ? Is it MyISAM ? How many partitions are there in table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarted mysqld after increasing open file limit to 40000 in my.cnf

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_open-files-limit

This has solved this issue.